# Different date time formatting output on java & moment js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

We have a requirement, where we want to use a consistent date time format across server side code & on mobile client javascript code. We decided to go with moment.js, for date formatting on client side. However the outputs of the two are not in sync.

```
Time Format String:  "**YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ**"
```

Java Code & Output

```
    java.util.Date d2 = new java.util.Date();
    SimpeDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(d2);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);


Output:2015-02-06T03:28:24.333+0000
```

Moment JS Output

```
    var d2 = new Date();
    var format = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ";
    alert(moment(d2).format(format));

Output: 2015-02-06'T'03:28:24.333+0000
```

With moment.js, T is coming in quotes. 
  Similary, if the format is "**YYYY-MM-DD'TXYZ'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ**". 
    Java output: 2015-02-06TXYZ03:28:24.333+0000, 
    Moment output: 2015-02-06'T1423193658Y+05:30'09:04:18.351+0530

Can someone suggest me a solution, or a better alternate.

Comment: Why would you automatically think it would match Java?  Moment is its own thing.  Folks use it with all sorts of different back-ends.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a java compatible ZonedDateTime using moment and format:

```
moment(this.date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSZ')
```

Comment: The `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSZ` format didn't work for me, but this does: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ` (removing the last `:SS` before the `Z`) -- or alternatively you could probably add a third `S`

Answer (score 1):

> var format = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Try leaving off the quotes around 'T' when you set the format.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, the time formatter has to be consistent across the server side and client side code. Also, it's not just about T. There could be other character's as well. Java formatter, simply places, as it is, everything inside quotes. But moment does not seem to be doing so.